# Qt - Write Speed - What's the fastest method to write a file in Qt?

Tags: c++, performance, qt, file

I already found some posts relating to Qt and writing a file with C++, but I didn't find a comparison of existing methods and a satisfying answer to the question "What's the fastest method writing a file in Qt?"...

The task:
I need to write a whole bunch of double values (around 500.000 up to 1.000.000) to file to a file. Due to my program structure, this values are saved in a QList, which contains some QVectors (every QVector has same size). The QVectors contains the double values. Additionally, each column (each QList element is a column) has to be written with different precision. Each column is seperated with a \t.

I tried several methods:

- QTextStream to a QFile with operator <<
- Directly writing to a QFile with QFile::write
- FILE and fwrite

In the end I got the best results with QTextStream and FILE using fwrite (nearly same speed), QFile with the QFile::write was a little bit slower (maybe 30%).

But I still think that there must be a faster method. For 500.000 double values my PC (Core2Duo) needs about 2s, and that's quite very long.

I also thought about using the Boost Karma C++ Library - can you recommend it?
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma.html

Comment: Do you absolutely need to write them as text?  Converting doubles to text is a pretty significant bottleneck.

Comment: If you really care about performance, you probably should start by replacing both `QList` and `QVector` by `std::vector`, as QT containers are not movable. If that is not possible, you should at least replace the `QList` by `QVector` for better cache behavior.

Comment: On a side note, you may want to consider [QSaveFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsavefile.html)

Comment: Hello, @paddy: Yes, a .txt file is necessary because we process the data with several programs afterwards

Comment: And @Corristo and TheDarkKnight - Thanks, I will try this out and post the results!

Comment: @Corristo That's just incorrect. A `QList` of a type that has the alignment and size no greater than a `void*` has the layout and performance of a `QVector`. Qt containers certainly are movable - they have been so for almost 3 years, since Qt 5.2! There'll be no performance benefit to `std::vector` here. Zilch.

Comment: There's no such thing as "writing" values to a file: it's too generic to be meaningful. How do you want these values "written"? Is it a binary file? A text file? If text file, are you parallelizing conversion from floating point to text? And so on. Please give a *complete* and *minimal* example.

Comment: @KubaOber I have to admit I was wrong regarding moveabilty of the QT containers, nevertheless you left out the important part of that quote from QTs documentation regarding the layout of list:
"Internally, QList<T> is represented as an array of T if sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*) **and T has been declared to be either a Q_MOVABLE_TYPE or a Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE** [emphasis mine]"
But `QVector` is neither a `Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE` nor a `Q_MOVABLE_TYPE`, so you get non-contiguous allocations for the `QVectors` inside the list, and hence probably a lot of cache misses.

Comment: @KubaOber Even the QT documentation says QVector should be the default: "QVector should be your default first choice. QVector<T> will usually give better performance than QList<T>, because QVector<T> always stores its items sequentially in memory, where QList<T> will allocate its items on the heap unless sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*) and T has been declared to be either a Q_MOVABLE_TYPE or a Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE using Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO. See the Pros and Cons of Using QList for an explanation."

Comment: I missed that the list was storing vectors, not floats :/ You're right of course that a `QVector<QVector>` is preferred over `QList<QVector>`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are doing it like below, it is unlikely you will find anything faster than fwrite.

```
double values[1000] = {...};

fwrite(values, sizeof(double), 1000, f);
```

Comment: Hi Sven, ok I will try this out, thanks! I tried `ofstream << setprecision << double-value;` right before and it was still slower than QTextStream. Is there a possibility to format the precision with using fwrite?

Comment: @johnymow I think you missed the most important part: `fwrite` writes binary data as-is, it doesn't write it as text. Your question doesn't indicate why you need the data as text.

Comment: Hi, sorry für the long delay of ~1 year, I was very busy and found a working solution for my programs which I use now.

Comment: @Kuba Ober: Of course file write was not very specific. In my company we need to generate text files with multiple colums and a lot of rows (10.000 - ~10.000.000 Values) and specific format for each column (precision, Scientific or Floating) for further processing in Excel, Matlab, Origin and for sharing data with customers ...

Comment: What I use now is still a QList<QVector<double> > for storing the values. It would take huge effort to change it to another type in approximately 10 programs ... Let's say there are historical reasons ;-). For writing I use snprintf to format the double values and storing them in a char array, seperated with tab or newline. For writing I use QFile::write(char*, ...) which performs good.

Comment: And again @Kuba Ober: The whole process of converting and writing runs in a seperate QThread including a queue for outstanding write operations. This makes file writing a one liner in the main program and works well for me :-)